# civicrm membership sync module for backdrop

Tags: backdrop

I have downloaded and installed the above module for backdrop, but when I try to set an association to a membership role, I get an error of:

Error
array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given

It doesn't give me any information and I need it to work.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What PHP version are you on? Do you have any more info in the logs? When you say you downloaded this module -- you are using the one that comes included with the CiviCRM package, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here by @Pradeep Nayak:

- https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/46023

> Regression from recent changes in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/150

> Fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/169/files

> Patch: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/169.patch