# civicrm membership sync module for backdrop null array

Tags: civimember, error, backdrop

[Similar question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45519/civicrm-membership-sync-module-for-backdrop)

I've the same problem with new installation of CiviCRM in Backdrop on my own Debian 12 machine:

```
array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given
```

when trying to set up a Association Rule for matching CiviCRM Group Administrators to Backdrop Role Administrator.

In the log nothing more IMO:

```
TypeError: array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in array_keys() (line 586 of /var/www/html/backdrop/modules/civicrm/backdrop/modules/civicrm_group_roles/civicrm_group_roles.module).

Backdrop CMS: 1.26.2 PHP Version: 8.2.7 CiviCRM: 5.67.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Regression from recent changes in https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/150

Fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/169/files

Patch: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-backdrop/pull/169.patch

Comment: I tried to change that line manually but now the error is:
   "max(): Argument #1 ($value) must contain at least one element"
and in the log:
   "ValueError: max(): Argument #1 ($value) must contain at least one element in max() (line 586 of /var/www/html/backdrop/modules/civicrm/backdrop/modules/civicrm_group_roles/civicrm_group_roles.module)."

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: thanks but having patched the file I still get the same error registering new user to Backdrop:
  _civicrm_group_roles_validate_groups(): Argument #1 ($group_ids) must be of type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/backdrop/modules/civicrm/backdrop/modules/civicrm_group_roles/civicrm_group_roles.module on line 108

Comment: And when trying the association:
  Undefined constant "rules"

And I don't get it. If this patch has been there for almost a year, why it haven't made it to the current archive?